# Why are personal weapons in Voyager larger than in other series?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, weapon, phaser

Personal weapons in all other Star Trek series can kill or stun at various settings but are the size of cell phones or small pistols.

Why are the ones on Voyager larger?

Comment: Those are [phaser *rifles*](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Compression_phaser_rifle). Bigger = more settings, longer-lasting battery, independent targeting, etc

Comment: I always just assumed the rifles were bigger and shaped that way so you could grip them like a rifle for better aim. The handheld phasers are already more powerful than anyone could need.

Answer (score 5):

Hand-held phasers are personal weapons that, like those on our times, can come in different sizes with different features and usages.

Phaser rifles are not featured only in Voyager, but in other series too.

A broad classification of Starfleet hand-held phaser weapons is as follows:

## Type 1

[image]

A [type-1 phaser](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Type_1_phaser) was the smallest, most basic weapon carried by Starfleet and other Federation personnel. Type 1 phasers were typically carried when it would be inappropriate to carry a larger weapon, such as on diplomatic missions, or "undercover" work.

## Type 2

[image]

A [type-2 phaser](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Type_2_phaser) or phaser pistol was a typical hand-held directed-energy phaser weapon used by Starfleet and United Federation of Planets personnel during the late-22nd, 23rd, 24th and 29th centuries.

More powerful and generally larger in size than the type 1 phaser, type 2 phasers were kept aboard Starfleet and Federation starships, starbases, space stations, and at planetary facilities.

## Type 3

[image]

A [type-3 phaser](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Phaser_rifle) (often simply referred to as a phaser rifle) was the Federation classification for the more powerful rifle variant of the standard Starfleet handheld phaser.

24th century phaser rifles had sixteen power settings, fully-autonomous recharge capability, multiple-target acquisition, and gyro-stabilization. They were slightly less powerful but much more sophisticated than Cardassian phase-disruptor rifles; some, such as Major Kira Nerys, considered them less effective in the field as their complexity made them less robust.